# Post Component re-renders even other instance of Post Component is called

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to web development and is trying to learn react and redux.

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC3y8-rFHvwheJHvseC3I0HuYI2f46oAK

As I'm trying to extend what I learned,

I'm trying to list all the users (clickable), 
once clicked will display (expand/collapse) all the post of the selected user (clickable again), 
once post is clicked, will display (expand/collapse) all the comment on that selected post

APIs to use:

- users: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
- posts: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId={user.id}
- comments: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId={post.id}

Right now, I was able to list all the users and able to do the expand/collapse, 
and also able to display the post of the user however, I am experiencing below problem:

If I click on user[0] it will expand and display the post of user[0] (**OK**).

then if I click user[1], will expand and display the post of user[1] (**OK**)

however upon click of user[1] it also changes the post listed on user[0] to list the post of user[1] as well (**NOT OK**)

here is my `UserContainer.js`

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { fetchUsers, updateUser } from "../redux";
import PostsContainer from "./PostsContainer";

function UsersContainer({ userData, fetchUsers, updateUser }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = event => {
    //console.log(userData.users)
    const indx = userData.users.findIndex(obj => obj.id == event.target.value);
    //console.log(indx)
    userData.users[indx].collapse = !userData.users[indx].collapse;
    //console.log(userData.users[indx].collapse + " " + indx);
    updateUser(userData);
  };

  return userData.loading ? (
    <h2>loading</h2>
  ) : userData.error ? (
    <h2>{userData.error}</h2>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <h2>User List</h2>
      <div className="list-group">
        {userData.users.map(user => (
          <div>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
              key={user.id}
              onClick={handleClick}
              value={user.id}
            >
              {user.name}
            </button>
            {/* for update to change SampleContainer component to POST component */}
            {!user.collapse && (
              //<SampleContainer id={user.id} name={user.name} />
              <PostsContainer id={user.id} />
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    userData: state.user
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchUsers: () => dispatch(fetchUsers()),
    updateUser: users => dispatch(updateUser(users))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UsersContainer);
```

I don't know why stackoverflow finds my post have code that doesn't properly formatted therefore I wasn't able to put the PostContainer component.

here is the codesandbox link for complete reference of the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-testing-mi6ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the posts of that particular selected user at an instance, so change the state `posts` of `postsReducer` to object to store the posts of multiple users

Please find the code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-testing-9hw6o)

**EDIT**

If you want to prevent the loading indicator for other users then, you need to store the array of ids that are currently being loaded, and remove id once the data is loaded, for that you need to  update the way you are dealing with loading state of reducer from boolean to array

Please find the updated sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-testing-9hw6o)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Thank you for this one bro.. this helps me, you even do fix my code on sandbox. However, I tried the code but, if I click on the user, any expanded users also re-renders, although the data is correct but the re-rendering process is not good as it will call the api multiple times. is there a way to stop re-rendering once the data is already loaded, and will only re-renders once clicked again? Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Wow, you got exactly what I need to do. what's left is for me to study your changes to the code. It seems there's a LOT for me to learn. Thank you very much for this bro..